# What's a good platform for independently teaching computer science and programming?

Tags: programming

I've been interested in becoming a computer science/programming educator for a while now, and I have a real passion for it.

I've taught a few people to code through sites like Khan Academy by answering questions and making examples and things, and I also tried out teaching on Reddit a bit, as well as Discord (through their video calling and screen sharing platform). I've taught a few people, but I would enjoy teaching more people, and with a more regular and consistent schedule.

I've thought about platforms like Udemy, but I much prefer to teach on a more personal level, where I can be there with them while they try to code things and answer all their questions and provide them with examples and things. More of a tutoring sort of thing rather than just pumping out content.

Do you guys know of any good ways I could get started? I'm not interested in teaching for a university or a highschool or anything like that at the moment, I'm mostly just looking for a way for me to get in touch with students online.

Even if you don't feel like you have a perfect answer, feel free to share your thoughts and let me know what you think/if you have any ideas. Any comment or answer is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite broad, but I *think* you're suggesting that you wish to tutor, and wish to tutor programming specifically.  In which case, I'd consider tools like Zoom and repl.it.

The ability to live-code alongside your tutee, and watch as the work, closely approximates the experience of sitting at the same computer.  A video-conferencing app then allows you to talk directly, and the whiteboard feature of Zoom allows you to draw on a common paper together while you analyze problems together.

Comment: Oh wow! I had never heard of or seen repl.it before. That seems like a very interesting tool, and I will certainly check it out in the morning. I may be able to make something work using that and other platform like Zoom or Discord. Thank you very much for your suggestion!

Comment: VSCode has a live share plugin - https://code.visualstudio.com/learn/collaboration/live-share - that'll let you code on the same file at the same time, similar to repl.it. I've used it a few times with remote students.